# Slide menu like youtube

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm trying to create a slide menu like the Youtube one (that menu when you click the settings in the video player, see the gif below).

[image: Slide Menu]

### HTML Code

```
<div class="menu-box">
    <div id="panel-1" class="menu-panel active">
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 3</span></div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel-2" class="menu-panel">
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 3</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS Code

```
.menu-box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: width .15s, height .15s;
}

.menu-panel {
    display: none;
}

.menu-panel.active {
    display: table;
}

.menu-item {
    display: table-row;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.menu-item .caption {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
}

.menu-item .caption.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

### My Problem

To make the slide effect, I can use the `transform` from the css, but how I will show the panel 2?

The default display of the panel is `none`, if I set the display to table (when it's active), the menu-box will not smoothly resize.

So.. my problem is to make that nice transition between panel 1 to panel 2 (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

`transition` works only with numerical values. changing from `display:none` to `display:table` won't work with transition.

try to use `transform` instead. i made an example for you

you can also use `opacity` to hide elements and then use transition.

in the below example. when you click on the `click me button` the first `panel` gets class `active` and appears. and then when you click on either of its elements, the second panel appears from left

it's just an example to help you. Let me know if it worked for you

```js
$("button").click(function(){
          $("#panel-1").addClass("active")
         $("#panel-1 .menu-item").click(function(){ 
                    $("#panel-2").addClass("active")
})
})
```

```css
.menu-box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

.menu-panel {

  transition:0.5s;
}
#panel-1 {transform:scaleY(0) ;transform-origin:top}
#panel-2{ transform:translateX(-100%)}
#panel-1.menu-panel.active {

      transform:scale(1);
}
#panel-2.menu-panel.active {

      transform:translateX(0);
}


.menu-item {
    display: table-row;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.menu-item .caption {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
}

.menu-item .caption.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Click Me
</button>
<div class="menu-box">
    <div id="panel-1" class="menu-panel">
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 1 - Item 3</span></div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel-2" class="menu-panel">
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><span class="caption">Panel 2 - Item 3</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```